# What is the best phrase to tell students that they should get a worksheet from the board?

Tags: american-english, academia

I work as a teacher. I created several worksheets that I pinned to the board right across my door. I want students to pick up as many of them as they need so that they can study at home. What is the best way of saying this?

-Please take one

-Help yourselves with the worksheets

-Go ahead and take one

-You are welcome to take one

-Anything else?

Thanks

Comment: You *hang **from** the board across ...*.

Comment: They must be ***in*** *a hanging wall file.* Or *pinned to* the board?

Comment: Three of your options ask to *take one*. Offering to take one doesn't allow to *pick as many of them as they need*.

Comment: Hmm, that's right. What would be a better alternative than "pick as many of them as you need" ?

Comment: Please take any worksheets you need.

Comment: *Please, help yourselves* has a nice double-meaning.

Comment: Is "help yourselves with handouts" ok or would it be better to say "help yourselves to handouts"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Please take one -- fine

-Help yourselves with the worksheets -- Help yourselves to the worksheets

-Go ahead and take one -- avoid this one

-You are welcome to take one -- Please feel free to take a worksheet

Additional: 
-Help yourself

Answer (score -1):

<s>WORMS!</s> Dear Class,

<s>I TIRE OF YOUR FOOLISH ERRORS!</s> 
 You may take one (or more) handouts if you would like to do extra work at home.

<s>FUTURE MISTAKES WILL NOT BE TOLERATED!</s> Have a nice day, and feel free to ask me if you have any questions!

(Signature)